# Upgrading Ruby installation on Mac OS running Snow Leopard 10.6.5

Tags: ruby, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade, rvm, macports

I have a Mac Os running Snow Leopard 10.6.5 and I am trying to upgrade my Ruby installation.

Before I did anything, I run the following commands and I had the following results:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

So, to upgrade my installation, I installed first **macports** and then Ruby using [Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) (RVM).

```
1. bash < <(curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head)
2. mkdir -p ~/.rvm/src/ && cd ~/.rvm/src && rm -rf ./rvm/ && git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm.git && cd rvm && ./install
3. rvm install 1.9.2
4. rvm 1.9.2 --default
```

After that, I run the following commands and I had the following results:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ rvm list
=> ruby-1.9.2-p136 [ x86_64 ]
```

**Why Ruby is still at 1.8.7? What is wrong? Or, what I forgot?**

Comment: MacPorts / RVM install new versions of Ruby to a location that is probably not in your PATH.

Comment: How I can get the correct PATH name and how/where I must set that?

Comment: FYI, RVM doesn't need or use MacPorts. They're kind of at odds and can cloud the issue for you. I'd recommend picking one or the other. I prefer RVM but it's your choice.

Comment: Whatever you do stop using RVM right now. It will randomly delete gems, destroy Ruby core executables, date your grandmother then dump her on Valentines Day, steal your credit cards, wreck your car, and vote the exact opposite way you do just so your votes don't count. But seriously, stop using RVM, it's horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

Edit the '**.profile**' file in home directory:

Add the line at the bottom:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

and then in the **Terminal** run

```
source ~/.profile
```

to set the changes.

Comment: Instead of adding additional comments as answers, you should edit your original question to show updates.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the "Post Install" instructions in the [RVM installation page](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) and add the following line to one of your ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile files?

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

That's really important to get RVM working correctly.